# Artificial key meaning in databases

Tags: database, computer-science

What is the meaning of "artificial key" of an entity set in database design?Is it an attribute that is not natural to the entity set?Is it something assigned by a "global organization"?For example: Social Insurance number. Can you provide some brief examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An artificial key is one that has no meaning to the business or organization.

Artificial keys are permitted when

1) no attribute has all the primary key properties, or

2) The primary key is large and complex.

For Example: Enrollment table from business point of view has (student, c1ass) combination as primary key. But this primary key is large and complex, so DBA decides to add row_id column as primary key. Here, row_id can also be called as Artificial Key.

Source http://ecomputernotes.com/database-system/rdbms/type-of-key